# New-TimeSpan -Start cannot be bound. Value is no DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0

I have to get the difference between a DateTime and Sysdate in seconds.

This code worked well for months. Since I put it into a function, I'm getting the error:

> New-TimeSpan : The parameter "Start" cannot be bound. The Value "06/14/2016 09:50:42" cannot get converted into "System.DateTime". Error : "String is no valid DateTime."

(translated in own words because console output is German)

```
function _CalcRunningTime
{
  param( [String] $p_sDatetime )
  $sSYSDATE    = Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"                
  $oCulture    = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
  $p_sDatetime = [DateTime]::ParseExact( $p_sDatetime, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", $oCulture )
  $sSYSDATE    = [DateTime]::ParseExact( $sSYSDATE, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", $oCulture )
  $oTIMESPAN   = New-TimeSpan –Start $p_sDatetime –End $sSYSDATE
  $iSeconds    = ($oTIMESPAN.Hours * 3600) + ($oTIMESPAN.Minutes * 60) + $oTIMESPAN.Seconds

  Return $iSeconds
}
```

Input format of `$p_sDatetime` is e.g. `06.14.2016 09:50:42`. After `ParseExact()` the format is like shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not re-use variables or parameters, and don't convert `DateTime` values to strings and parse them back to `DateTime` values. Also, calculating the difference between two `DateTime` values will give you a `Timespan` object (which already provides you with a ready-made method to get the total number of seconds). No need to go out of your way and use a cmdlet or manually calculate the number of seconds. Using the [`return`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) keyword is optional too.

Simplify oyur function to something like this:

```
function _CalcRunningTime {
  param( [String] $p_sDatetime )

  $culture    = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo('de-DE')
  $parsedDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($p_sDatetime, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $culture)

  ($parsedDate – (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
}
```

Cast the number of seconds to an integer if you don't want fractions of a second:

```
[int]($parsedDate – (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: The Function TotalSeconds isn't highlightes for me. I'm getting an error: the return value of my func cannot be converted into System.Int32.

Comment: @Mike Can't reproduce. The property `TotalSeconds` should return a double, which is convertible to integer.

Comment: Sry, I can't reproduce it anymore too ... for me this works now too ... I guess I had another problem anywhere and I mixed things up. Thanks you sir.

Answer (score 0):

At least for now this seems to work fine for me:

```
# ------------------ Func: _CalcRunningTime ------------------
function _CalcRunningTime
{
    param( [String] $p_sDatetime )

    $sSYSDATE   = Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    $oTIMESPAN   = New-TimeSpan –Start $p_sDatetime –End $sSYSDATE

    Return $oTIMESPAN.TotalSeconds
}
# ------------------ Func: _CalcRunningTime ------------------
```